# What is the Microsoft equivalent of VMWare Workstation?

Tags: vmware-workstation, hyper-v

What is the Microsoft equivalent of VMWare Workstation?

I.e. what is their workstation/desktop tool to run virtual machines?

I use VMWare workstation extensively, but have a lot of .VHD file images, and I'd prefer to just boot those.  Is there a version of Hyper-V that I can run on my desktop?

(I'm running Windows 7 64 bit ultimate if that information helps)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microsoft Virtual PC:

http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/default.aspx

You could also run the Microsoft Hyper-V Server 2008 R2 Hypervisor, but it does not run on the desktop:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=3512

Comment: Thanks @KCotreau.  Is virtual-pc a viable replacement for VMWare Workstation?

Comment: @Ken Shaw Personally, I don't think it is in the same league. I have used Virtual PC before, and while I don't use VMWare workstation specifically, I have used VMWare server for years through versions 1, 2 and ESXi. I am pretty that it is similar to VMWare Server, and based on that, I made my statement. VMWare WS would be worth the money to me.